# How to wire this Buffton motor

Tags: ac, induction-motor

I bought this motor at a scrap yard and would like to wire it up for 120 volt power.

There are 5 wires coming from the motor, a black, white, ground and two yellows. One yellow is numberer "2" and the other is "8".

Inside the motors the terminals seem to be numbered from 1 to 5 with each having two spade connectors except number 5. The black wire is connected to number one and the white wire connects to number 2. A yellow and a purple wire are attached to number 4 and number three and five are empty.

I'm not familiar enough with wiring diagrams on Motors 2 figure out how it relates to the wires I'm seeing in the motor, and searching online didn't bring up any additional information for this particular motor.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Wiring Diagram]
[image: The wires I have]

Comment: V on the diagram is "violet" your "purple" wire, so the motor is currently configured for 115V, 60Hz operation.

Comment: if you are seeing yellow wires coming out of the motor and not connected they may be for a 'run' or 'start' capacitor.

Comment: looks pretty beat up for a 2 year old motor,

Answer (score 1):

The label on the motor should provide the most reliable information. It seems to indicate that the "low" and "high" voltages are 115 and 208-230.  For "low voltage" or 115 volt operation, it shows yellow and violet wires connected together on terminal 4 and power connected between 1 and 2. If the internal wiring is already connected, I wouldn't worry about the black and white wires connected to 1 and 2 respectively vs. 2 and 1 as marked on the label. Just connect power to terminals 1 and 2 and ground to the ground terminal.

If you have a meter or some other means to check for shorts and grounds. It would be a good idea to check that there isn't a shorted winding or a grounded winding. It appears that the full-load current should be 13.8 amps. The no-load current might be anything from 1/3 to 2/3 of that.

Comment: Should the two yellow wires just be capped and ignored then?

Comment: perhaps they're for a starting capacitor.

Comment: I missed the part about 2 yellow wires coming out as loose wires in addition the the yellow connected to the violet on terminal 4. They could easily be for an external capacitor that is missing. I f there is not a capacitor in or on the motor, there is almost certainly a capacitor that is requires but missing.